# subsonic Substage how can i override a class name

Tags: class, substage

Is there anyway to override the class name generated as its causing me problems when generating tables.  Im getting clashes as i have property names the same names as some of my tables.

This causes duplicate name compile time errors on my classes.

Answer (score 1):

See [SubSonic Conventions](http://subsonicproject.com/setup/subsonic-conventions/)

> Column names should not be the same as table names.

In short, unless you are willing to change and rebuild SubSonic from sources, just rename the conflicting column names.